# problem restricting deletion of a django model value

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a foreign key, that when the object it references gets deleted will be filled with a default value via a callable `on_delete=models.SET(callable)`..   However, I have problem with that because in the Django admin site I'm able to delete the callable value that it has passed to the foreign key and since my foreign key can't be null this is going to raise a server error which I don't like.. so I want to handle that error through the Django admin site itself if that is possible and I know it is.. also if you have better thoughts on this, I really appreciate your help.

As a temporary solution I had overrode the `QuerySet > delete()` method of the referenced model to skip deleting the object through the Django admin site bulk deletion. I'm sure that there is a better way than this.

The foreign key:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    marektplace_tag = models.ForeignKey('tags.MarketplaceTag', on_delete=models.SET(default_marketplace_tag))
```

the callable:

```
# Model: Product
def default_marketplace_tag():
    from tags.models import MarketplaceTag
    tag = MarketplaceTag.objects.get_or_create(name='None')        
    return tag[0].id
```

The referenced model:

```
class MarketplaceTag(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, validators=[only_letters])
```

Comment: If you remove the default object, it will create a new one and reference to that one.

Comment: That's not going to happen since the default gets checked before deletion and if it's not there it gets created, otherwise nothing happens and a server error of  'IntegrityError' comes up.